# How to say: after have waited or after waiting e.g. 4 hours ?

Tags: grammaticality

I' like to know which one of these (or maybe there is another correct way to say it)is correct:

- after have waited ( e.g. 1 hour )
- after waiting  ( e.g. 1 hour )

Comment: Also OK:  "After I have waited 1 hour", "After he has waited one hour".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*After waiting an hour* is correct. The first one would be *after having waited an hour*.

But *after an hour* works and is shorter.

Answer (score 4):

*After waiting an hour* is fine. *After having waited an hour* is unlikely, because *after* is unnecessary.